# Elementary Hoare logic proof

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, formal-proofs

I would like to prove that the following Hoare triple is correct by giving a full Hoare logic proof. (Assuming all variables are real.) How can I do so?

$$\{c = 0\} ~ a := −c; ~ b := a + c; ~ c := a ~ \{ab = c\}$$

---

My Attempt using the assignment, concatenation, and weakening rules:
$$ \{c = 0\} \Rightarrow \{\} \iff \{-c(-c + c) = -c\}$$
$$a := −c;$$
$$\{a(a + c) = a\}$$
$$b := a + c;$$
$$\{ab = a\}$$
$$c := a$$
$$\{ab = c\}$$

Comment: Frankly speaking, I have difficult to unserstand... If $c=0$ and we set $a=-c$, also $a$ must be $0$.

Comment: Now, setting $b=a+c$ we get again $0$.